# Server-side rules For Exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010

Is there a powershell command or an attribute in ADSIEdit that will tell me or validate that the rule is create on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

You mean the inbox rules? There is an [powershell command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351062(v=exchg.141).aspx) for it:

This example retrieves all Inbox rules for the mailbox Joe@Contoso.com.

```
Get-InboxRule -Mailbox Joe@Contoso.com
```

[A rule will always be server-side unless the Exchange server simply cannot do what the rule asks of it.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/0c291a0f-047d-4a5c-bbed-328935940b86/how-to-force-the-outlook-rule-to-be-serverside?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy)

Comment: I have a client that is creating a rule that she needs to run without the shared mailbox open so I asked her to create the rule in OWA.  She said she did but still not working on weekends.  How can I validate that the rule was created on the server? Is there an attribute in this command shown above that can tell me that if I add a full list command to this command?

Comment: So the mailrule should be running in the shared Mailbox not in the user mailbox? If that is true then she need to create the rule via OWA. The question here is now. DID you see that rule with my command above?

Comment: yes - i saw that rule and several others running the -InboxRule command

Comment: ok, then your question should be answered with that posting. The rule is in that mailbox. So please accept the answer then. If you need some help to troubleshoot why that rule isn´t running i think the best one would be to open a new question with additional infos like you provided in the comments.

Comment: So what you are saying is that if I see if in the PS command, then it is a server-side rule?  There are no attributes or views to see that can confirm this?